# Add hover, onmouseetner, onmouseleave functions to css class, Syntax

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Im having trouble with basic syntax.
I want to use jquery to select all elements in a CSS class, 
then add an action when the user hovers on the item

```
$(".item").hover(function(){$(this).fadeTo(100, .1)});
```

is it possble to assign different functions to onmouseenter and onmouseleave as well? I'm having a bit of trouble locating similar code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With `.hover()`, you can pass two functions.

```
$(".item").hover(
    function(){$(this).fadeTo(100, .1)},
    function(){$(this).fadeTo(100, 1)}
);
```

These will be assigned as `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` events.

---

Of course you could do it manually as well.

```
$(".item").mouseenter(function(){$(this).fadeTo(100, .1)})
          .mouseleave(function(){$(this).fadeTo(100, 1)});
```

---

Or you could even reuse the same function, and just test the event object.

```
$(".item").hover(function(event){
    $(this).fadeTo(100, event.type === 'mouseenter' ? .1 : 1);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible.

```
$(".item").hover( function(){ /* onmouseenter */ }, function(){/* onmouseleave */} );
```

Answer (score 0):

`hover` can take one or two event handlers. If one is supplied (as in your example) it's applied to both `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` events. If two are supplied, each event gets it own handler.

More information is in the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/hover/).

From the look of your example I assume you want to fade the element back in on `mouseleave`, if so try this:

```
$(".item").hover(
    function(){ $(this).fadeTo(100, .1) },
    function(){ $(this).fadeTo(100, 1)} ); 
);
```